# matDatePicker with angular cloud firestore and [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, ngmodel, angularfire5

With Real Time Database, I used the angular material matDatePicker to save date news.

Since I have moved on with firestore collection, when I call the saved date in an angular service, it shows it as an object

```
  "date": {
     "seconds": 1529445600,
     "nanoseconds": 0
  },
```

and I can't use it with [(ngModel)]. It looks like it's no longer a string so the matDatepicker matInput doesn't recognize it anymore.

So how should I bind the matDatepicker value in to the ngModel of my view?

Template:

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" 
        placeholder="Date" required readonly
        [(ngModel)]="news.date"
            (ngModelChange)="updateField(news,'date',news.date)">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix type="button" [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Service:

```
getNewsWithKey(key: string): Observable<SingleNews> {
const newsPath = `news/${key}`;
this.news = this.afs.doc<any>(newsPath)
  .snapshotChanges().map(action => {
    const $key = action.payload.id;
    const data = { $key, ...action.payload.data() }
    return data;
  });
return this.news}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the object that is being saved is of type [`firebase.firestore.Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp). This change was added in [Firebase JS SDK `v4.13.0`](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore_7), where JavaScript `Date` objects will be saved of type `Timestamp`.

In the `Timestamp` class, there's a method called [`toDate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#toDate), which converts the `Timestamp` to a JavaScript `Date` object.

Here's what you can do:

- You can try assigning a temporary object with the converted `Timestamp` and whatever data is saved remotely.

  ```ts
  getNewsWithKey(key: string): Observable<SingleNews> {
    const newsPath = `news/${key}`;
    this.news = this.afs.doc<any>(newsPath)
      .snapshotChanges().map(action => {
        const $key = action.payload.id;
        const data = Object.assign(action.payload.data(), { date: action.payload.data().date.toDate(), $key: action.payload.id });
        return data;
      });
    return this.news;
  }
  ```